# Delete table row in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

i have a table and a hidden field inside a td in it which stores the primary key .while deleting the table row i like to retrieve  this value and add it to another hidden field

i want to retrieve  the data in hidden field for this deleted row ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete the row, likely using [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) you can still query it's elements, for example using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest("tr").remove().find("input[type=hidden]").val();
  //do something with the ID
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/e9bLj/1/)